# Keep duplicate lines notepad++

Tags: search, text, replace, notepad++

I need to remove the unique lines and keep the duplicates in my text file(read the articles written to remove duplicate lines but I want to do the opposite). Is there any way I could do that using expressions or textfx? 
E.g:

```
file1.txt
hello
world
hello
```

After operation, output should be

```
hello
hello
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Replace dialogue:

Find:

```
^(.+)\r?\n(?!(.|\r?\n)*\1)
```

Replace:

```
*leave empty!*
```

Options:

- Select radio button "Regular Expression"
- Leave checkbox ". matches newline" unselected

Pros:

- Duplicate line doesn't need to be immediately after the 1st occurrence

Cons:

- If a line appears `x` times in your data, after the regex `x-1` occurrences will be left and not `x` as asked in OP.

Comment: OK, by reading your other comment in phresnel's post it looks like your data has non-word characters too like `<`. I have updated my answer. Check again.

Comment: Sorry about that
So if my file contents are
`alpha
alpha
foxtrot
foxtrot
delta`
and I run your regex, output comes as 0 occurances occured

P.S: how do I add new lines in code block?

Comment: Ya much better. Now the output is 
`alpha
 foxtrot
 delta`

Delta is being displayed although it occurs only once

Answer (score 0):

This finds all lines *followed* by a line repetition (it does NOT find the last line, though):

```
.+\r\n(?=(.+\r\n)\1)
000000    111111 22
```

This matches a non-empty line 0, but only if it is followed by (a non-empty line `\1`, which is followed by `\1`).

Note that this assumes `\r\n` (Windows) line separations. On a Unix text file, just `\n`, on a Mac text file, just `\r`.

In the search box, mark `Regular expression`, unmark `. matches newline`, `Replace with` = "".

Example:

```
"Zulu
 Alpha
 Alpha
 Bravo
 Charlie
 Charlie
 Delta
 Echo
 Echo
 Foxtrott
"

(file ends with empty line)

-->

"Alpha
 Alpha
 Charlie
 Charlie
 Echo
 Echo
 Foxtrott
"
```

Comment: In your regex, if the file is for example
`alpha
alpha
foxtrot
foxtrot
delta`
The output comes as:
`foxtrot
foxtrot
delta`

Comment: @Rahul, I tested phresnel solution and works as described! Are you sure you deselected the ". matches newline" checkbox?